# merge a single record into an activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to end up with a collection of users which will receieve an email. The users will be all the admin users + a specific person.

I get the admin users by executing

```
to = account.employees.where(:admin => true)
```

This returns multiple records. I can get an additional single individual by executing

```
special_user = User.find(x)
```

but how do I put them together so that I end up with one group. I tried

```
to = account.employees.where(:admin => true)
special_user = User.find(x)
to = to.merge(special_user)
```

but am getting undefined method `includes_values`

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active record associations are arrays, so you can use the [array `<< (append)` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), like this:

```
to << special_user
```

Comment: I tried that earlier. I've just realised it DOES work, but to.count isn't being updated for some reason. If I just look at "to" it's added the extra person, but to.count still shows the original number. Bizarre!

Comment: @GarethBurrows I know this can be odd, but does `to.length` suffer the same problem or returns the updated number of records?

Comment: @GarethBurrows you can see the difference between ActiveRecord `count`, `length` and `size` in [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html).

Comment: thanks for that. You are correct, to.length shows the updated count. All sorted :)

Comment: Image2.limit(2) << Image2.first

undefined method `<<' for #<Image2::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd4659501f0>